# multiple choice question on topology of matrices

Tags: general-topology

Which of the following are true?

a)The set of symmetric positive definite matrices are connected.

b)The closed unit ball centred at $0$ and of radius $1$ of $l_1$ is compact

c)The set of invertible matrices on R forms a set of measure $0$.

d)The set of symmetric matrices in $M_n (\Bbb R)$ is dense.

I am clueless!! advanced thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) true, they are path connected look $x^T[tA+ (1-t)B]x$ is again positive definite symmetric

b) false as $l_1$ is  not finite dimensional  norm linear space.

c) false, as The set of invertible matrices on R is dense, open, so must contain open ball with positive measure (intuitively)

d) False, they are closed subset in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ as you see they are the inverse image of $0$ matrix under the continuosu map $f:M_n(R)\to M_n(R)$ $f(X)=X-X^T$